# Limits for Inner/Outer Queries using Parse.com to send Push Notifications?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, subquery, limit

I know that Parse.com limits queries by default to `100` objects, and that you can set the query limit manually to `1000` objects... That said, I have also read that the **Push Notification's 'where' query DOES NOT** limit the amount of objects you can target...

```
Parse.Push.send({ 
    where: unlimitedQuery,
    data: {
        alert: "Push Message Text"
    }
});
```

My question is about passing Inner/Outer queries into the Parse.Push object as the "where" property -- Are these Inner/Outer queries still subject to the 100-1000 object limit, or are they also free from this constraint?

Comment: Have you tested this? What would unlimitedQuery target, wouldn't that have to be a Installation query? If so, then you could create a bunch of instances and see if the query limitations pass through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse Query limits is not applicable to push notifications. Push Query will not be affected by the limits and you can send push to as many number of people as per the parse.com plan you are subscribed to.